# How can I change this insert function to work in a linked list using strings?

Tags: c++

This is the first question that I'm posting on StackOverflow, so forgive me if it seems kinda choppy.

For my computer science class, we're working with a double linked list for the current assignment. One of the functions required is an insert function.

I actually found an insert function on StackOverflow earlier this week, but it was set up to use structures inside of the main file instead of separate class files like this project is using. I think the function can work, but I'm not sure what alterations I need to make so that it can work with class files instead.

> LinkedList.h member data

```
private:
    Node *head, *tail;
    mutable Node *it;
    int count;
```

> Insert function

```
bool LinkedList::insert(const string & str) const
{
    LinkedList * tempVar;
    if (hasMore) {
        resetIterator();
    }
    else {
        Node * temp = new Node;
        //temp = str;
        temp->data = str;
        temp->next = it;
        temp->prev = nullptr;
        it->prev = temp;
        it = temp;
    }

    if (it != nullptr) {
        Node * current = it;
        Node * previous = nullptr;
        Node * tempNode = nullptr;

        while (current->next != nullptr) {
            tempNode = current->next;

            if (current->data > tempNode->data) {
                swap(current->data, tempNode->data);
            }
            else {
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
        tempVar->count += 1;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I haven't been able to test it yet due to not knowing what alterations are needed, but the function should insert strings that are passed into the argument into the linked list, as well as sort them in a dictionary style. Right now the only error is that temp = str; not working, and I'm not entirely sure what I need to do to get it to work.

Comment: You don't need an iterator as a data member of your list class.  It doesn't belong in there.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If you're referring to count, that's used to keep track of how many strings are stored in the linked list. Sorry, should've clarified that.

Comment: actually, I was referring to `mutable Node *it;` That doesn't belong in the class.  Iteration is always a local operation, so methods should use local iterator variables as needed.  You never need to carry an iterate across multiple methods using a class data member.

Comment: Huh, alright. That was in the code that my instructor gave us, so maybe he's wanting it there for a specific reason?

Comment: Or, maybe your teacher just doesn't know any better? We see a LOT of questions on StackOverflow that stem from code and instructions given by teachers who don't teach C++ properly.

Comment: I suppose that's possible. He seems like a good teacher though. What would you suggest I do instead of what he has us doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
bool LinkedList::insert(const string & str)
{
    Node * current = head;

    while ((current) && (current->data < str))
        current = current->next;

    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = str;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    newNode->prev = nullptr;

    if (current)
    {
        if (current->previous)
        {
            current->previous->next = newNode;
            newNode->previous = current->previous;
        }

        current->previous = newNode;
        newNode->next = current;

        if (current == head)
            head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!head)
            head = newNode;

        if (tail)
        {
            tail->next = newNode;
            newNode->previous = tail;
        }
        tail = newNode;
    }

    count += 1;
    return true;
}
```

That being said, you really should be using the standard [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) container instead of implementing a double-linked list manually.

Comment: Shouldn't you insert `newNode` *before* `current`?